# How can I count dot in the string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to count number of dot `.` in the string. I am trying with `match()` function for counting the dot, but it does not working.

I tried same script to count other string, letter and `-` which is properly working. I have following string

```
var string = "How are you doing . - today? You . - are such a nice person!";
```

I tried following script

```
var num = string.match(/-/g).length; // output 2
var num = string.match(/are/g).length; // output 2
var num = string.match(/a/g).length; // output 4
var num = string.match(/./g).length; // output 60
```

Can someone guide me why it `match` function does not support `.` and how can i count it. I would like to appreciate.

Comment: Dot has a special meaning in regex, it matches with any character. Escape the dot ... `string.match(/\./g).length`

Comment: @gurvinder372 It is works for me thanks +1

Comment: You can use this trick `string = "How are you doing . - today? You . - are such a nice person!.";console.log(string.split('.').length);`

Comment: @Mr.Developer, or use `brackets` like in my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The dot `.` is used in regex and matches a single character, without caring which character. You need to escape the dot, like `string.match(/\./g).length`. The `\` is the escape, and says to treat the dot as a true `.`, instead of the special regex meaning.

Comment: is it empty string safe?

Comment: Empty string, yes. If the string is null, then you'll want to check `string != null` first to avoid an NPE.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the `.`

```js
var string = "How are you doing . - today? You . - are such a nice person!";
var num = string.match(/\./g).length;
console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dot is a special character in regex and it matches with any char.

You have to use **escape** the dot.

```js
var string = "How are you doing . - today? You . - are such a nice person!";
var num = string.match(/\./g).length; // output 60
console.log(num);
```

Another approach is to use `brackets`.

```
var num = string.match(/[.]/g).length;
```